# pass variable through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass id from one script to another through javascript, i have been able to pass one id, but i am not able to understand how to pass 2 id

I have another id stored in $requestid variable, i wish to pass it in the following code so that i can call it in c_getinfo.php page

```
<span class='ListId' data-id="<?php echo $row1['id'];?>">

<script>
  $('.ListId').click(function(){
        var Id=$(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({url:"c_getinfo.php?Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".ShowData").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

can anyone please tell how i can do so, without making much changes to original code

Comment: See [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Use `data` property. Also, use `type` to set the type - `GET/POST...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.

Add another data attribute `data-requestid` to the same span element.

Get it the way you are getting id and pass it.

You are done.

Corrected code:

```
<span class='ListId' data-id="<?php echo $row1['id'];?>" data-requestid="<?php echo $requestid?>">

<script>
  $('.ListId').click(function(){
        var Id=$(this).attr('data-id');
        var requestid=$(this).data('requestid');
        $.ajax({url:"c_getinfo.php?Id="+Id+"&requestid="+requestid,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".ShowData").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You could also retrieve data like `$(this).data('id')`.

Comment: @R.Oosterholt, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: `"c_getinfo.php?Id="+Id+"&requestid="+requestid`. This URL will be visible on console.So `Use data: {key:value} and Method : POST` in your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you can sent the $.post data by the $.get or $post method

```
$.post('c_getinfo.php', { field1: "id", field2 : "requestid"}, 
        function(returnedData){
             console.log(returnedData);
    });
```